# pass string to InetSocketAddress

Tags: java, string, arguments

Is there a way to pass a string argument to the parameters of `InetSocketAddress`?

this is correct way to generate proxy:

```
SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9050);  
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, addr);
```

But I want to create method to take in a string like this:

```
method("127.0.0.1",9050);  

public void method (String a){  
SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(a); //can't place string here is there away forit work?  
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, addr);    
}
```

Is there any way to get new `InetSocketAddress` to take the string IP?

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass the port to the constructor too, not just the IP address:

```
method("127.0.0.1",9050);

public void method (String a, int port){  
    SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(a, port);
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, addr);    
}
```

Comment: I was just writing that... +1.